# searchable recyclerview android with json data как сменить загрузку из сервера на запрос с Assets

Tags: android, json, парсер, recyclerview, assets

Нашел [урок](https://camposha.info/android-examples/listview-search-json) как сделать `ListView` c поиском и база данных через `json.` Но проблема в том что там json файл находится в онлайне, а не в самой программе. А мне нужно что бы `Json` база данных была в папке **ASSETS**. 
Я понял что нужно заменить эту часть кода где приложение будет искать json файл в интернете, но как корректно её заменить на ту часть где нужно искать в папке **ASSETS**.  я не знаю
    AndroidNetworking.get(JSON_DATA_URL)
Вот полностью код

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /*
    Our data object
     */
    public class Spacecraft {
        /*
        INSTANCE FIELDS
         */
        private int id;
        private String name;
        private String propellant;
        private String imageURL;
        private int technologyExists;
        /*
        GETTERS AND SETTERS
         */
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getPropellant() {
            return propellant;
        }
        public void setPropellant(String propellant) {
            this.propellant = propellant;
        }
        public String getImageURL() {
            return imageURL;
        }
        public void setImageURL(String imageURL) {
            this.imageURL = imageURL;
        }
        public int getTechnologyExists() {
            return technologyExists;
        }
        public void setTechnologyExists(int technologyExists) {
            this.technologyExists = technologyExists;
        }
        /*
        TOSTRING
         */
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }
    class FilterHelper extends Filter {
        ArrayList<Spacecraft> currentList;
        ListViewAdapter adapter;
        Context c;

        public FilterHelper(ArrayList<Spacecraft> currentList, ListViewAdapter adapter,Context c) {
            this.currentList = currentList;
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.c=c;
        }
        /*
        - Perform actual filtering.
         */
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults filterResults=new FilterResults();

            if(constraint != null && constraint.length()>0)
            {
                //CHANGE TO UPPER
                constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

                //HOLD FILTERS WE FIND
                ArrayList<Spacecraft> foundFilters=new ArrayList<>();

                Spacecraft spacecraft=null;

                //ITERATE CURRENT LIST
                for (int i=0;i<currentList.size();i++)
                {
                    spacecraft= currentList.get(i);

                    //SEARCH
                    if(spacecraft.getName().toUpperCase().contains(constraint) )
                    {
                        //ADD IF FOUND
                        foundFilters.add(spacecraft);
                    }
                }

                //SET RESULTS TO FILTER LIST
                filterResults.count=foundFilters.size();
                filterResults.values=foundFilters;
            }else
            {
                //NO ITEM FOUND.LIST REMAINS INTACT
                filterResults.count=currentList.size();
                filterResults.values=currentList;
            }

            //RETURN RESULTS
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
            adapter.setSpacecrafts((ArrayList<Spacecraft>) filterResults.values);
            adapter.refresh();
        }
    }

    /*
    Our custom adapter class
     */
    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

        Context c;
        ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts;
        public ArrayList<Spacecraft> currentList;
        FilterHelper filterHelper;

        public ListViewAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts) {
            this.c = c;
            this.spacecrafts = spacecrafts;
            this.currentList=spacecrafts;
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return spacecrafts.size();
        }
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return spacecrafts.get(i);
        }
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return i;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if(view==null)
            {
                view= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.model,viewGroup,false);
            }

            TextView txtName = view.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
            TextView txtPropellant = view.findViewById(R.id.propellantTextView);
            CheckBox chkTechExists = view.findViewById(R.id.myCheckBox);
            ImageView spacecraftImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.spacecraftImageView);

            final Spacecraft s= (Spacecraft) this.getItem(i);

            txtName.setText(s.getName());
            txtPropellant.setText(s.getPropellant());
            //chkTechExists.setEnabled(true);
            chkTechExists.setChecked( s.getTechnologyExists()==1);
            chkTechExists.setEnabled(false);

            if(s.getImageURL() != null && s.getImageURL().length()>0)
            {
                Picasso.get().load(s.getImageURL()).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).into(spacecraftImageView);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(c, "Empty Image URL", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.placeholder).into(spacecraftImageView);
            }
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(c, s.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            return view;
        }
        public void setSpacecrafts(ArrayList<Spacecraft> filteredSpacecrafts)
        {
            this.spacecrafts=filteredSpacecrafts;

        }
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            if(filterHelper==null)
        {
            filterHelper=new FilterHelper(currentList,this,c);
        }

            return filterHelper;
        }
        public void refresh(){
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    /*
    Our HTTP Client
     */
    public class JSONDownloader {

        //SAVE/RETRIEVE URLS
        private static final String JSON_DATA_URL="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Oclemy/SampleJSON/338d9585/spacecrafts.json";
        //INSTANCE FIELDS
        private final Context c;

        public JSONDownloader(Context c) {
            this.c = c;
        }
        /*
        Fetch JSON Data
         */
        public ArrayList<Spacecraft> retrieve(final ListView mListView, final ProgressBar myProgressBar)
        {
            final ArrayList<Spacecraft> downloadedData=new ArrayList<>();
            myProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            AndroidNetworking.get(JSON_DATA_URL)
                    .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                    .build()
                    .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                            JSONObject jo;
                            Spacecraft s;
                            try
                            {
                                for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++)
                                {
                                    jo=response.getJSONObject(i);

                                    int id=jo.getInt("id");
                                    String name=jo.getString("name");
                                    String propellant=jo.getString("propellant");
                                    String techExists=jo.getString("technologyexists");
                                    String imageURL=jo.getString("imageurl");

                                    s=new Spacecraft();
                                    s.setId(id);
                                    s.setName(name);
                                    s.setPropellant(propellant);
                                    s.setImageURL(imageURL);
                                    s.setTechnologyExists(techExists.equalsIgnoreCase("1") ? 1 : 0);

                                    downloadedData.add(s);
                                }
                                myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            }catch (JSONException e)
                            {
                                myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Toast.makeText(c, "GOOD RESPONSE BUT JAVA CAN'T PARSE JSON IT RECEIEVED. "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        }
                        //ERROR
                        @Override
                        public void onError(ANError anError) {
                            anError.printStackTrace();
                            myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(c, "UNSUCCESSFUL :  ERROR IS : "+anError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
            return downloadedData;
        }
    }
    ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts = new ArrayList<>();
    ListView myListView;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myListView= findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        final ProgressBar myProgressBar= findViewById(R.id.myProgressBar);
        SearchView mySearchView=findViewById(R.id.mySearchView);

        mySearchView.setIconified(true);
        mySearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
        mySearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(query);
                return false;
            }
        });
        spacecrafts=new JSONDownloader(MainActivity.this).retrieve(myListView,myProgressBar);
        adapter=new ListViewAdapter(this,spacecrafts);
        myListView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Нужно поменять класс `JSONDownloader` так что бы он не искал в интернете и закачивал базу данных Json а находил её в папке Assets. Нуже для кого-то эта смена кода пара секунд а я уже неделю сижу и ничего не могу сделать так что бы оно заработало.

```
 private  void  loadJson(){
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try{
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("Json файл в асетах")));
            String temp;
            while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(temp);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        parseJson(sb.toString());
    }
```

**Или помогите найти нормальный урок по searchable recyclerview android with json data** где json файл в середине приложение а не где то на сервере

Comment: Они все нормальные, просто их нужно понять, а для этого сесть и разобраться, вы же хотите чтобы вы просто скопировали и всё работало. Всё нужно делать постепенно: вот хороший урок по JSON через GSON https://metanit.com/java/android/13.3.php, делаете его и разбираетесь как он работает. Дальше, хорошая статья по RV, прикручиваете её и разбираетесь что да куда, сюда вам нужно будет передать List<Phone>,но у вас это будет что-то другое вместо Phone.А потом прямиком сюда:https://habr.com/ru/post/111475/,хотя лучше:https://software.intel.com/ru-ru/articles/creating-a-search-field-in-your-android-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подсмотрите у [кошатника](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/assets.php), как работать с `assets`, дальше как со строки сделать `JSONArray`, потом меняете этот метод:

```
public ArrayList<Spacecraft> retrieve(final ListView mListView, final ProgressBar myProgressBar)
{
    final ArrayList<Spacecraft> downloadedData=new ArrayList<>();
    myProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
    myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    JSONArray jsonArray = loadJson();
    JSONObject jo;
    Spacecraft s;
    try
    {
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
        {
            jo=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            int id=jo.getInt("id");
            String name=jo.getString("name");
            String propellant=jo.getString("propellant");
            String techExists=jo.getString("technologyexists");
            String imageURL=jo.getString("imageurl");

            s=new Spacecraft();
            s.setId(id);
            s.setName(name);
            s.setPropellant(propellant);
            s.setImageURL(imageURL);
            s.setTechnologyExists(techExists.equalsIgnoreCase("1") ? 1 : 0);

            downloadedData.add(s);
        }
        myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    }catch (JSONException e)
    {
        myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(c, "GOOD RESPONSE BUT JAVA CAN'T PARSE JSON IT RECEIEVED. "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return downloadedData;
}
private JSONArray loadJson(){
    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    try{
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("Json файл в асетах")));


        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        jsonArray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            br.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonArray;
}
```

ну в принципе и все, должно работать.
Хотя как по мне, вы сейчас пытаете откопать динозавра и подарить ему только что изобретенный велосипед. Почему бы вам не воспользоваться обычной БД (сейчас например модная такая вещь как `room` для работы с SQLite от `google`) или например тот же `Realm`? И наполнить ее через c того же asset при помощи `GSON` конвертера (если я конечно правильно понял вашу цель). Во вторых уже пора учиться работать с `RecyclerView`, `ListView` полезен для небольших, простых списков, но даже ля них рекомендуют `RecyclerView. Да и есть сейчас специальный [адаптер](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28995380/best-practices-to-use-realm-with-a-recycler-view)

UPD: Обновил участок кода. Добавь этот код вместо вот этого:

```
public ArrayList<Spacecraft> retrieve(final ListView mListView, final ProgressBar myProgressBar)
    {
        final ArrayList<Spacecraft> downloadedData=new ArrayList<>();
        myProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        AndroidNetworking.get(JSON_DATA_URL)
                .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                .build()
                .getAsJSONArray(new JSONArrayRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        JSONObject jo;
                        Spacecraft s;
                        try
                        {
                            for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++)
                            {
                                jo=response.getJSONObject(i);

                                int id=jo.getInt("id");
                                String name=jo.getString("name");
                                String propellant=jo.getString("propellant");
                                String techExists=jo.getString("technologyexists");
                                String imageURL=jo.getString("imageurl");

                                s=new Spacecraft();
                                s.setId(id);
                                s.setName(name);
                                s.setPropellant(propellant);
                                s.setImageURL(imageURL);
                                s.setTechnologyExists(techExists.equalsIgnoreCase("1") ? 1 : 0);

                                downloadedData.add(s);
                            }
                            myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        }catch (JSONException e)
                        {
                            myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            Toast.makeText(c, "GOOD RESPONSE BUT JAVA CAN'T PARSE JSON IT RECEIEVED. "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                    //ERROR
                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError anError) {
                        anError.printStackTrace();
                        myProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        Toast.makeText(c, "UNSUCCESSFUL :  ERROR IS : "+anError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
        return downloadedData;
    }
```

Comment: Читал я эту статью кошатника. Но не могу понять. Я должен просто открыть кодом этот файл а вот распределение текста будет уже в том коде что Вы написали. Или нужно распределять текст самому. На name id recipe и ТД.?

Comment: JSONArray jsonArray = //получаем ваш JSONArray через assetManager

Comment: Assets manager должен быть выше вашего кода или ниже? Я кажется  понял что с асетов нужно взять только массив а вот распределение уже Вы написали

Comment: Вам просто нужно поменять этот участок кода и в переменную `jsonArray` передать из `asset-ов` массив.

Comment: изменил я вопрос.Написал как я написал AssetsManager. но не знаю где там вызвать `jsonArray` и перевести в то место где вы написали. Может для вас это пара секунд а для меня целая вечность что бы понять эту кодировку.

Comment: в последней строке класса `loadJson` у меня `return new JSONArray(builder.toString());` **builder** написан красным как это исправить?

Comment: @VladBulan, писал на коленке, исправил